# Take an XML file and an XSL file and make an HTML string out of them?

Tags: java, html, xml, xslt, servlets

I have 2 strings, an XML string I constructed using Java DOM interface, and an external XSL file I want to bind to that XML file. I tried using Java transform methods, but without luck (meaning I can't seem to find any solution for this on the web).

**How do I take an XML file and an XSL file and make an HTML string out of them?**

What I'm trying to do is to inject an XML page into my JSP page.

**Just to clarify:** *This is done in a servlet, not in JavaScript.*

**A little more information:**

I create the XML during runtime as a string, the XSL file I've got is stored on the server, what I want to do is to display the XML altered by the XSL file to the user when he clicks on a certain link on the site, and I want to embed that inside an existing JSP page (in order to maintain the standard look of the site).

This is what I've got so far:

```
String convertedXML = new String();
TransformerFactory factory1 = 
    TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Source xsl = new StreamSource("my.xsl");
Result result11 = null;
try {
    Templates template = factory1.newTemplates(xsl);
    Transformer transformer1 = template.newTransformer();
    Source xml = new StreamSource(xmlString);
    result11 = new StreamResult(convertedXML);
    transformer1.transform(xml, result11);
} catch(Exception e) {
   System.out.println("Not Good");
}
```

The last line before the catch throws the next error:

> javax.xml.transform.TransformerException:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.getOutputHandler(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   controllers.UserController.schedulePage(UserController.java:394)

Comment: So are you just wanting to load the contents of two files into strings? What does this have to do with XML/XSLT/HTML? What do you mean "bind" an XSL file to an XML file? What does "without luck" mean - you got an error? you got the wrong result? What does your Java code look like?

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Are there any error messages? Surely the exception handling could emit something more useful than "Not Good"?

Comment: The Source (Source xsl)  and the result don't seem to contain the file/string contents

Comment: @nayish: this is much better... Now what does your code currently do? Does it throw an exception and print "Not Good"? If so, have it print out the actual exception instead. What exception is it?

Comment: What is `xmlString`? If you supply a string argument when constructing a [StreamSource](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamSource.html#StreamSource%28java.lang.String%29), that string is supposed to be an URL.

Comment: I am facing some performance issue on similar code in PROD. Any pointers ?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46194800/converting-xmlxsl-in-html-using-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you put your file into WEB-INF and try to use following:

```
String path = "/WEB-INF/my.xsl";
ServletContext context = getServletContext();
InputStream xslIs = context.getResourceAsStream(filename);
Source xsl = new StreamSource(xslIs);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've got an answer as yet but the code provided (as indicated by mzjn above) is clearly incorrect, as the argument provided to the StreamSource is meant to be a system identifier (a file locator) or a File, not a String that will be overwritten. If you want to write your output to a String, use this construction:

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
result11 = new StreamResult(writer);
// do your transform...
transformer1.transform(xml, result11);
// now obtain your result's output...
String out = writer.toString();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I haven't touched this in a long time, but I'm pretty sure that the selected answer was good enough for me at the time...